# How to downgrade a package and all its dependencies in RStudio?

Tags: r

I need to use an older version of the Seurat R package to reproduce some projects. However, if I do so, all its dependencies stop working. Also, I don't want to downgrade a bunch of packages just for this job.

I work in RStudio. I thought to create a conda environment with older versions of packages. But as far as I know, RStudio doesn't work with conda environments. Is there any way to make another 'environment' in RStudio with an older version of Seurat and its old dependencies?

Comment: If you have version that you want to install, you can use this on terminal `install.packages("package_name", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", version = "1.2.3")`

Comment: Look at pkg:packrat.

Comment: A standard, native R, way to create environments is [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/).